# Разбить сроку на 3 массива

Tags: php, массивы

Здравствуйте!

есть строка `jquery,bootstrap/pace,cookie/main`

1. в начале нужно разбить сроку по слешу и получить массив

`Array([0] => jquery,bootstrap [1] => pace,cookie [2] => main)`

2. Далее разбить каждый из элементов массива по запятой и получить 3 массива.
3. В переменную jsCore положить первый массив, в переменную $jsPlugins второй массив и в переменную jsApp третий массив.

Прошу помощи в реализации!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сначала разбиваете строку на массив по символу `'/'` с помощью `explode()`, а потом ним же разбиваете по запятой:

```
$str = 'jquery,bootstrap/pace,cookie/main';

//[$jsCore, $jsPlugins, $jsApp] = array_map(function($item){// PHP 7.1
list($jsCore, $jsPlugins, $jsApp) = array_map(function($item){
    return explode(',', $item);
}, explode('/', $str));

var_dump($jsCore, $jsPlugins, $jsApp);
```

Comment: Эдуард дополнил вопрос 3 пунктом, прочтите пожалуйста

Comment: Эдуард, получил ошибку (Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '=' in)

Comment: у меня версия (PHP Version 7.0.21)

Comment: Вернее, для php 7.1 - для php 7 нужно заменить конструкцию `[]` на `list()`. Сейчас отредактирую ответ.

Comment: Эдуард благодарю за помощь. и хочу уточнить будет ли работать list() в 7.1 и выше?